# how to change the language from english to hindi using i18next for signup form in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, forms, authentication, internationalization, google-signin

I am trying to change the signup  and login page  which contains input fields of name, password, email, confirm password displayed in english to hindi but not able to do it. can you let me know how to do it. i have found that hindi language is not available for translation in i18 so do i manually change all the input fields in both signup and login page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you‘re new to i18next.
i18next is an i18n framework, it will not automatically translate content.

Have a look at this guide to learn more about it: https://dev.to/adrai/how-to-properly-internationalize-a-react-application-using-i18next-3hdb